# Mongo username and email unique fields validation

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I want to tell the user which one is already taken if is Username or Email but the way Im validating this is in the save function if this finds a duplicate it will give you a error 11000 but I cant specify which one is already taken. I want the error to give an index or something I can put in a if statement explaining which one is the duplicate key so I can be more specific with the error. Is there a way i can accomplish this? Also why Im getting always index: 0? Shouldn't be different for each field?  Let me know if you have any questions.

**Schema**

```
var user = db.Schema({
  name:       { type: String,  required: true},
  username:   { type: String,  required: true, index: { unique: true }},
  email:      { type: String,  required: true, index: { unique: true }},
  password:   { type: String,  required: true, select: false},
  admin:      { type: Boolean, required: true},
  verify:     { type: Boolean, required: true},
  created_at: { type: String,  required: true, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: { type: String,  required: true, default: Date.now },
  campaigns_donated: []
})
```

**Post Action**

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
  var user = new User()

  user.name     = req.body.name
  user.username = req.body.username
  user.email    = req.body.email
  user.password = req.body.password
  user.admin    = false,
  user.verify   = false

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.code == 11000) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'username or email already taken'})
      } else {
        return res.send(err);
      }
    }
    res.json({ success: true, message: 'User created'})
  })
})
```

**Pre Save Function**

```
user.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this
  // hash the password only if the password has been changed or user is new
  if (!user.isModified('password')) { return next() }

  //Generate Hash function
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err)  return next(err)
    //Change Password to hash
    user.password = hash
    next()
  })
})
```

**Console log error**

```
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: ReachPeeps.users.$username_1 dup key: { : "xandor" }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: ReachPeeps.users.$username_1 dup key: { : "xandor" }',
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: ReachPeeps.users.$username_1 dup key: { : "xandor" }' }
```

Comment: Isn't what you need right there in the error message?  The `$username_1` part is the violated index name which tells you there's already a doc with a `username` of `"xandor"`.

Comment: I solved it Using mongoose-unique-validator [link](https://github.com/blakehaswell/mongoose-unique-validator)

Comment: The problem with using a validator approach is that it's not atomic and you still end up having to handle the unique index violation if you want a fully robust solution.

Comment: what would be a better solution in that case? @JohnnyHk

Comment: Better to just handle the unique exception, parsing the message to get the details.